# If after certain date - filter list

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

I have a master list of people from a mailing list. Right now I have it set up so it checks if someone is a volunteer and if they are it takes their data and puts them onto a volunteer list. Now I want to first check if the volunteer was added to the list after April 1st, 2019.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TYh6ywSU_LjdCdZViaBWBSf8sBsXl6wQjCjItzdiojg/edit?usp=sharing

This is the link to an example master data sheet plus what my volunteer sheet looks like now and what it should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **A2**:

```
=FILTER('Master Data Sheet'!A2:A, 
        'Master Data Sheet'!D2:D="Yes", 
        'Master Data Sheet'!E2:E>DATE(2019, 4, 1))
```

paste in **C2**:

```
=FILTER({'Master Data Sheet'!C2:C, 'Master Data Sheet'!B2:B}, 
         'Master Data Sheet'!D2:D="Yes", 
         'Master Data Sheet'!E2:E>DATE(2019, 4, 1))
```

[image: 0]